# Why is click event handler for a submit button in a colorbox defined in a jQuery prototype method not invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events, colorbox

I have added a function to jQuery prototype as below. What I want to do is when this method is invoked, generate an html form based on the arguments passed to the method and show it in a colorbox.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.myFunction = function(data){
    
    var form = $('<form name="people"></form>');
    
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
          
        var match = data[index];
        $('<input type="radio" name="person">' + match['name'] + ' [' + match['uri'] + ']<br> ')
        .attr("value", match['uri'])
        .appendTo(form);
    }

    $('<input type="button" id="a_button" value="Add"/><br>')
    .appendTo(form);
    
    var list = $('<div>').append(form).html();

    $('#a_button').click(
            
            function(){
                console.log('message from event handler');
            }
    );
    
    $.colorbox({ innerWidth:420, innerHeight:315, html: list });
};

})(jQuery);
```

As you can see, form has a button called Add using which I hope to make an ajax request. But unfortunately click event handler attached to this button doesn't seem to be invoked.

Does anyone have any idea about what's wrong here? `myFunction` is actually invoked by a drupal ajax command in case if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the form to the DOM *after* attaching the event handler.

`$('#a_button')` searches the DOM at *that specific point in time*, but the form is not added to the DOM until after your call to `colorbox` with `list` as a parameter.

Try a permanent *delegated event handler* instead (or simply add the click handler after the `colorbox` line).

### e.g.

```
$(document).on("click", "#a_button", function(){ 
    console.log('message from event handler');
});
```

### or

```
$.colorbox({ innerWidth:420, innerHeight:315, html: list });
$('#a_button').click(

        function(){
            console.log('message from event handler');
        }
);
```

Comment: I have tried the first suggestion before but unfortunately it gives `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`. Second suggestion doesn't work either :(

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery `on` was introduced in jQuery version 1.7 is is definitely the way to go for a lot of event handling needs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hmm, the error says it all! Drupal 7 by default comes with jQuery 1.4.4 hence the problem. Thanks so much for the answer.